# Confidence interval 3d

Tags: statistics, matlab, confidence-interval

I have a data set consisting of 3 columns: $x$, $y$ and $z$. I am analyzing the influence of $x$ and $y$ on $z$: [image of the scattered data and fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9yOu.jpg)

I have managed to find a surface fit of the form $z=10^{a+bx+cx^2+d\log{y}}$ in Matlab, which should represent a mean. I would like to find a new surface of a similar form that represents the 95% confidence interval and another one that represents the 5% confidence interval. More specific: I want to find a function $f(x,y)$ that represents the values for which $z$ is smaller than $f(x,y)$ with a confidence level of 95%, and the same for the 5% confidence level. Is this possible and how? Specific ways in Matlab are appreciated, but I'm looking for a general method.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is phrased in a way that makes me hesitate over its meaning. Often one would speak of a confidence interval for the _mean_ of $z$ for particular values of $x$ and $y$, but if you mean a future observed value of $z$ rather than the mean of $z$, again for specified values of $x$ and $y$, that would usually be called a prediction interval rather than a confidence interval. This would depend on estimates of the "errors", i.e. the amounts by which observed values of $z$ differ from the mean for the fixed $x$ and $y$ values. ("Errors" are unobservable; "residuals" are$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$observable estimates of unobservable errors.)  There is one very hard question that might need to be considered: how to adjust the intervals for uncertainty in the model itself.  Another complication is that from your picture it looks as if you may have non-constant variance. $\qquad$

Comment: If this were multiple linear regression with homoscedastic errors, I might post an answer, since in such cases methods of finding confidence intervals and prediction intervals are well understood and found in all textbooks.  I think this question might fare better at stats.stackexchange.com and some aspects of it may be far over the heads of mathematicians-as-opposed-to-statisticians.  SUMMARY: This is more involved than a routine textbook problem. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you for your comment Michael. I probably did mean to say prediction interval instead of confidence interval, which proves my lack of statistical knowledge. I will post the question on stats.stackexchange.com as well.